# What should the View actually be doing?

Tags: marionette

After reading up on Marionette for the last couple weeks and MVC architecture in general, I'm still unclear what the View in MV* should actually be doing. Every code sample, blog post, or tutorial I've read puts different amounts of logic in the View or uses essentially deprecated `.on` event handling.

My gut tells me that the Model holds data, the View fire events, and the Controller listens for and acts on those events. I strive to keep as much logic out of the View as possible, as weird as that might sound.

As an example, I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MkZ2u/) that simply switches one view to another using `.listenTo` in the controller. I could have used Layouts and switched Regions around, but I wanted to keep the code as small as possible.

Am I on the right track? Should Views *only* present an interface and shout events without acting on any of them within the View code? Should this logic be in the Controller or does this move away from the principle of having lean controllers?

Thanks.

Here is the detailed code:

**HTML**

```html
<script id="part1-template" type="text/template">
    <%= part1blurb %> <input type="button" id="goToPart2" value="OK" />
</script>

<script id="part2-template" type="text/template">
    <%= part2blurb %>
</script>

<div id="main"></div>
```

**Model**

```js
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        part1blurb: 'This is part one',
        part2blurb: 'This is part two'
    }
});
```

**Views**

```js
var Part1View = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    model: new MyModel(),
    template: '#part1-template',
    triggers: {
        'click #goToPart2': 'part1:done'
    }
});

var Part2View = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    model: new MyModel(),
    template: '#part2-template'
});
```

**Controller**

```js
var PageController = Backbone.Marionette.Controller.extend({
    _views: {
        part1: new Part1View(),
        part2: new Part2View()
    },
    initialize: function () {
        this.listenTo(this._views.part1, 'part1:done', function() {
            this._showPart(this._views.part2);
        });
    },
    start: function () {
        this._showPart(this._views.part1);
    },
    _showPart: function(view) {
        PageTest.mainRegion.show(view);
    }
});
```

**App**

```js
var PageTest = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

PageTest.addRegions({
    mainRegion: '#main'
});

var controller = new PageController();

controller.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

My rule of thumb for a view is for It to remain pretty dumb.

Typically here is my method:

1. create view in controller
2. listen for certain events with listenTo
3. in my view, a DOM event occurs
4. my handler method only triggers and
           event up to the controller with the necessary data (the data
           gathering in the view Is the most logic I will have)
5. the controller listening to the fired event then handles more
   intense business
           logic (model saving, fetching, etc.)

The goal is to be able to change either the view structure or controller method without depending on one another. They are loosely coupled only by the data passed up from the view in the trigger.

Comment: So, you essentially would produce code like my example above then?